# Failed to parse XML

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I've been into my internship program for a couple of days now and my supervisor tasked me to get an overview and improve the program that her student had developed. The problem is I've never used android studio and never had experience in java programming during my school. Here's the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nursyafiqah.login">

android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here's the error that always pops up

ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\Arash Aiman\Documents\Project LI\KYB\Android Version\KYB1\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml ParseError at [row,col]:[6,30] Message: expected start or end tag Affected Modules: app

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have attributes that are not part of any tag, e.g `android:versionCode="1"` .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you attributes not inside a tag.
You can try below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nursyafiqah.login"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I tried adding the tag in the androidversionname="1.0" before and it didn't work as well..

Comment: But parsing error should have changed targeting row number. Please post it too

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should put

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

inside the tag.
and put the `</manifest>` at the end of the file.
just like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nursyafiqah.login"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Sorry but it seems like nothing changed.. i tried to add the manifest tag in the end and the build was nothing except failed parse..